# How to access route defined in spring config file in a Java program

Tags: java, spring, routes, apache-camel

I have a route defined as follows:

```
<camelContext id="camelContextABC" ... autoStartup="true">
    <route id="route1">
    .
    .
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I want to access the above route from my Java Program to be able to stop it on a given event.
How will I be able to access this route?

Comment: Use `RoutePolicySupport`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the control bus pattern

- http://camel.apache.org/controlbus

Or there is API on CamelContext to stop a route by calling the `stopRoute` method with the id of the route.

If you XML is in a Spring XML file, then you can get hold of CamelContext the standard spring way from the application context, where it has `getBeans` methods. Or use Spring's dependency injection to inject CamelContext into your code. But this is really just standard spring way.

For stopping a route in Camel check above, and also other questions here on SO as its been debated before